# Can we disabled the navigation controller of leftBarButtonItem that is back button of the view controller in iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, back-button

I want to disabled the default back button of navigation controller

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO; 
// Below code does not work since leftBarButtonItem is always nil.
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
```

I have done it with manually shown below, But Is there any property to disabled the default back button with just single line?

```
backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 100, 30)];
[backButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backbutton_100.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backButton addTarget:self  action:@selector(backAction:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[backButton setTitle:@"  All Customers" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
backButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
[buttonView addSubview:backButton];

UIBarButtonItem* leftButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:buttonView];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton;
[leftButton release];

// Now it is working.
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
```

Comment: The back button is the left one, so why are you trying to set rightBarButtonItem.enabled to NO? Shouldn't it be left? Also, please update your question and try to get your code showing properly. Use 4 spaces ("    ") at each line to make it aligned right. We're here to help, not to decrypt ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using "hidesBackButton=YES" is really not an elegant solution, cause it HIDES the button which is not what we want. An acceptable work-around would be adding a UILabel to the window just over the back button at least disabling the touches on the button.

Add this method to your AppDelegate class:

```
- (void) disableLeftBarButtonItemOnNavbar:(BOOL)disable
{
    static UILabel *l = nil;

    if (disable) {
        if (l != nil)
            return;
        l = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 160, 44)];
        l.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        l.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [self.window addSubview:l];
    }
    else {
        if (l == nil)
            return;
        [l removeFromSuperview];
        [l release];
        l = nil;
    }
}
```

You can call it like this from any view controller to disable:

```
MyAppDelegate *appDeleg = (MyAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDeleg disableLeftBarButtonItemOnNavbar:YES];
```

To enable:

```
MyAppDelegate *appDeleg = (MyAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDeleg disableLeftBarButtonItemOnNavbar:NO];
```

Comment: There's a bug with the code and a rotating device, you'd have to do an affine transform to get it to work properly in other orientations.

Answer (score 11):

Its very easy ..... just try this out

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.userInteractionEnabled = NO;   //for  disabling 

self.navigationController.navigationBar.userInteractionEnabled = YES; //for again enabling
```

Comment: It doesn't appear disabled (with dark gray text), but it works and is better than hiding the button. +1

Answer (score 2):

Call `[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];` for the view controller you do not want to have the back button. Then set the `leftBarButtonItem` as normal.

Comment: I want to disabled the button not hiding the button, thanks for your response

Comment: Why not create an instance of UIBarButtonItem, set it to the leftBarButtonItem, hide the backButton, and set the leftBarButtonItem to your button. Then disable the leftBarButtonItem.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
[[_navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem leftBarButtonItem] setEnabled:NO]; // The top view controller on the stack.
[[_navigationController.visibleViewController.navigationItem leftBarButtonItem] setEnabled:NO];// Return modal view controller if it exists. Otherwise the top view controller.
```

you can use this when you want to disable or enable UIViewControler from Appdelegate, or any other viewcontroler.